# jQuery plugin: Html autocomplete as in Dreamweaver

Tags: jquery

Is there any jQuery plugin that works as follows: when you type a tag like `<p>`, the editor will automatically add `</p>` and put the cursor after the first tag, it should also display a context sensitive list of valid tags.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so there are a hand full of wysiwyg edior such as

[Aloha](http://www.aloha-editor.org/)

[ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/)

[tinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)

Answer (score 0):

In Dreamweaver CS5, you can turn it on by selecting Edit/Preferences, a windows pops out. On the left hand side, choose Code Hints. On the right hand side, in the section Close tags, select After typing the open tag's ">". That's it.

Comment: What does that have to do with jQuery?